# How to handle large files with NSData?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, avurlasset, swiftydropbox

I have a very large video and I need to chunk this video to upload it to **Dropbox**.

I tried to use `NSData`, but because this file is too large, my application always crashes, so I don't know what I can do now.

For smaller videos, I used this:

```
NSData(contentsOfURL: self.newAsset.URL)!.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, 10000000))
```

and I didn't have any problem with that, but when the video is too large I have an error:

> Cannot allocate memory

So, what can I do to chunk the data of large videos?

Answer (score 2):

For best practice go with `NSURLSession` if you want to implement custom otherwise lots for third party library are there like `RESTKit` or `AFNetworking`. For `NSURLSession` the session `NSURLSession` supports three types of tasks: data tasks, download tasks, and upload tasks. All it support the background uploads/downloads as well. source([apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html))

- Data tasks send and receive data using NSData objects. Data tasks are intended for short, often interactive requests from your app to a server. Data tasks can return data to your app one piece at a time after each piece of data is received, or all at once through a completion handler.
- Download tasks retrieve data in the form of a file, and support background downloads while the app is not running.
- Upload tasks send data in the form of a file, and support background uploads while the app is not running.

Image Source [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started)
[image: Image Source:]

Answer (score 0):

You should use video file url to upload large data using NSURLSession

```
- (NSURLSessionUploadTask *)uploadTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request fromFile:(NSURL *)fileURL;
```